# Find range that contains most timestamps from list in Python

Tags: python, datetime, time

I have a list of timestamps of when an event A happens, and I want to figure out if there are certain time (within the hour) when A happens.

Here is a list of times when the event happens. I formatted a new line to signify a new day. From the list we can see that the event will likely happen between 7:50 am and 8:50 am every day. The output here should be about an hour range, and since 7:50 - 8:50 is the time range that contains the most amount of events, that should be the answer.How can I figure that pattern out using Python?

I tried rounding to the nearest hour and then finding the most common time, but that gave me 7 am - 8 am instead of 7:50 am - 8:50 am. For this problem, I'm assuming event A will happen every day.

Expected answer: 7:50 - 8:50

Why? Calculating the number of timestamps one hour ranges can cover:

1. 8:30 - 9:30:     2
2. 14:40 - 15: 40:  1
3. 20:40 - 21:40:   1
4. 8:40 - 9:40:     1
5. 20:00 - 21:00 :  2
6. 8:40 - 9:40:     1
7. 8:20 - 9:20:     3
8. 7:50 - 8:50:     4

```
import datetime
times = [datetime.time(8, 30), datetime.time(14, 40), datetime.time(20, 40), 
         datetime.time(8, 40), datetime.time(20, 00), 
         datetime.time(8, 20), 
         datetime.time(7, 50)]
```

Comment: "*I used a new line to signify a new day*" that seems kind of impractical to me, why not use datetime.datetime instead, with different dates? Also, what do you mean by "certain time" - mean? median?

Comment: @FObersteiner Sorry if it was not clear, the new line is just formatting to make it easier to read and make sense of.  If it makes sense to have just datetime, I could do that as well. I'm not super good with Python so I assumed having just times would be easier.
By certain time I mean the mode of the common times. In this example, it would just be 7:50-8:50 since there are no other common times. Does that make sense?

Comment: Ok seems that including dates in fact is not necessary here. How do you intend to define the interval - you say within one hour but expected output is off by 10 minutes (0750-0850)?

Comment: @FObersteiner Yeah, the output here should be about an hour range, and since 7:50 - 8:50 is the time range that can get the most amount of events, that should be the answer.

Comment: @FObersteiner do you have any other questions?

Comment: Python offers many options to calculate statistical quantities like the mode. But it's still unclear to me *how* you want to determine the interval around that. Can you give a minimal example for that in the question? Basically I think if you can give a clear description of the logic here, the actual code implementation won't be that difficult (even if you're new to Python).

Comment: @FObersteiner I added some extra explanation that I think might help. Does that help? Thanks for guiding me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work

```
from datetime import time, datetime, date, timedelta

def count_events(times):
    count = 0
    for t in times:
        delta = datetime.combine(date.min, t) - datetime.combine(date.min, times[0]) 
        if delta < timedelta(hours=1):
            count += 1
        else:
            break
    return times[0], (datetime.combine(date.min, times[0])+timedelta(hours=1)).time(), count

# your events list
times = [time(8, 30), time(14, 40), time(20, 40), 
         time(8, 40), time(20, 00), 
         time(8, 20), 
         time(7, 50)]

# sort times list before counting
times.sort()

# count events in intervals
intervals = []
for index, time in enumerate(times):
    intervals.append(count_events(times[index:]))

# find the interval with max events number
most_events = max(intervals, key=lambda item:item[2])

# print results
print('\n'.join(str(e) for e in intervals))
print(f'interval with max events is: {most_events}')
```

The result is

```
(datetime.time(7, 50), datetime.time(8, 50), 4)
(datetime.time(8, 20), datetime.time(9, 20), 3)
(datetime.time(8, 30), datetime.time(9, 30), 2)
(datetime.time(8, 40), datetime.time(9, 40), 1)
(datetime.time(14, 40), datetime.time(15, 40), 1)
(datetime.time(20, 0), datetime.time(21, 0), 2)
(datetime.time(20, 40), datetime.time(21, 40), 1)

interval with max events is: (datetime.time(7, 50), datetime.time(8, 50), 4)
```